# Does the mongoose web server have a shutdown handler?

Tags: mongoose-web-server

I am using the [Mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose) web server for my project.

Does Mongoose have a shutdown handler?

I would like to do some operations while the mongoose is shutting down.

Is it possible to see if the port is already used by another process or a mongoose server is already running?

Comment: whay exactly you want to do with port,sorry ?
for shutdown mechanism , mg_stop(context *ctx) is called

Comment: @AkshayPatil do mg_stop works if the process is killed?

Comment: I guess only SIGPIPE and SIGCHLD are ignored according to the code.
When I give "kill mongoose_pid" command on terminal then mg_stop() is automatically called and hence the mg_stop() works and mongoose process is killed.

Comment: @AkshayPatil i will check it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: There is no shutdown handler. There is no need for it, to be honest. Client code starts the server, and stops it, thus is knows exactly when the server is being shut down.

Question 2: With the latest version, you can get an error message for every option set, e.g.

```
 const char *err_msg = mg_set_option(server, "listening_port", "80");
```

This way you'd know if binding to a port has failed.